# How to fill the gap in Centered Moving Average using array?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

[SeeThePictureLink.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idPNO.png) I need Pine Script V5 code shifting left market data within array predetermined by variable x number of points and filling the gap with price points each equal to last price. I need such data array to construct Centered Moving Average. I believe using Array function would produce the most efficient and fast code (if I am wrong, please correct me)

Excel prototype [link] https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kyEyC9Rmb7grr69AzcOeGCzMDNow2n-s/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=101488649560849801546&rtpof=true&sd=true

```
//indicator should look like this:
//@version=5
indicator('LeftShiftedArrayWithGapFilled', overlay=true)
//Input
Shift = input.int(-100,"Shift", minval=-2500, maxval=0)
// Array calc.
LeftShiftedArrayWithGapFilled = //(your ingenious code expected here)
// CenteredMA with filled Gap to the right
CenteredMA = ta.sma(source = LeftShiftedArrayWithGapFilled.get(0),length = Shift*2)
//Plots
plot(LeftShiftedArrayWithGapFilled, 'LeftShiftedArrayWithGapFilled', color.new(color.blue, 0), 4)
plot(CenteredMA, 'CenteredMAWithGapFilled', color.new(color.red, 0), 4)
// On the negative, I don't want to see offset plot like that:
//plot(close, 'HistCloseArray with empty gap to the right', color.new(color.blue, 0), 4, offset = Shift)
//plot(ta.sma(close,Shift*2), 'CenteredMA unfinished', color.new(color.red, 0), 4, offset = Shift)
//, because that doesn't fill the gap to the right and plot can't be referenced by a function, thus does not solve the problem and besides that I know.
```

On the negative, I don't want to see offset plot like that:

`plot(close, 'HistCloseArray with empty gap to the right', color.new(color.blue, 0), 4, offset = Shift)`

`plot ( ta.sma (close,Shift*2), 'CenteredMA unfinished', color.new(color.red, 0), 4, offset = Shift)`

, because that doesn't fill the gap to the right and plot can't be referenced by a function, thus does not solve the problem and besides that I  know already.